# redirect in css to mobile friendly page with only css

Tags: css

I have a system in css that changes some of the page if you are on a mobile but there is only so much that you can do with css and I was wondering if I could use css to redirect the user to a mobile friendly page

---

**thanks any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: you can't redirect with css, not by itself anyway

Comment: No, you would use css to present a mobile friendly view OF the page. You probably want to start here Responsive Web Design -> https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Comment: You can use something called 'Media Queries' This is what you're looking for. The media queries use the browser agent to detect the size of the view port and changes what CSS is used based on that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is not redirecting the page with CSS, but rather changing the styling of the page with a CSS selector based on the screen size. You could do this with CSS's `media_query` selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries